How to debug an SSL handshake in more detail?
I'm working on a Java application that is failing to create a connection to an API for integration purposes. I'm getting a handshake failure and have gone so far as to use wireshark to grab the traffic. I'm semi confident that it's a TLS version issue.

I see the handshake failure, and the protocol shows TLSv1 which I'm guessing is the problem. Separately if I try to connect to this API using cURL or openSSL it works and shows TLSv1.3 in the protocol for the ClientHello bit.
If I look at the details of the ClientHello though, it shows TlSv1.2 as the requested protocol so I'm not sure why it's an issue.

Can anyone point me in a direction of how to get more information out of this? Bonus if someone can point me in a direction to make the Java application change it's behavior on this front.
PCAP: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qbzgU6L9AhPY8IPIy6KM1C6BP7ghOaAV/view?usp=sharing
Java debug of SSL Handshake:
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|17|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-04-04 21:42:19.180 EDT|ClientHello.java:640|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "450D606506B1335CBF914F1AF981CE839E0A832B5648DA495514698FB44C3002",
  "session id"          : "567D9AC550CAD29ACBEAF2328E9A51E9E5D167C97C8B6CA750BDD611AC48BE7D",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCAA), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "named groups": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
      [h2, http/1.1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: F9 2E FF DC 09 15 6C 94   D7 44 F4 95 00 C5 A0 EE  ......l..D......
            0010: C1 CD 97 E0 7E B4 77 05   B6 E9 2C 79 DB 83 A5 43  ......w...,y...C
          }
        },
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 6E FA 0C F4 C2 62 10   D0 98 44 1F F8 C5 A9 90  .n....b...D.....
            0010: 42 02 8D 42 B0 83 A7 11   15 C1 39 58 B7 17 E1 6B  B..B......9X...k
            0020: BC 19 00 BF 0D D1 98 D6   FF 87 4E A9 32 19 25 77  ..........N.2.%w
            0030: DB 0C 51 20 74 06 46 55   89 F8 56 32 B3 03 E4 DB  ..Q t.FU..V2....
            0040: A2 
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|17|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-04-04 21:42:19.208 EDT|Alert.java:232|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)



Which Java version are you using? Is the server a public one? Can you share the pcap of the conversation?

There is no easy tutorial on how to debug TLS problems. TLS debugging is unfortunately very hard, especially with limited information and even more with limited expertise. Ideally one has access to client side code, packet capture but also the server side (error logs etc). One also needs a good understanding of how TLS works, which means understanding the standard. Otherwise one is easily tempted to make the wrong assumptions and look into the wrong directions for solutions. Note for example that there are several places were TLS versions numbers are shown and what you see is perfectly normal.

In this case: handshake failure can be basically anything. But given that here the server reacts with a handshake failure to the ClientHello it must come from problems with the ClientHello. This can be missing or wrong SNI (very often), missing signature algorithms, missing ciphers (usually a different error), missing expected extensions, wrong TLS version support (although this is usually a different error) ... Ideally check with server side logs.

@MirceaVutcovici I updated the question to include a pcap and the java debug output.

@SteffenUllrich I have a support ticket into the vendor and it doesn't look like I'm going to get a ton of assistance on that side. The SNI issue is interesting, it's not something I've looked into yet so now I have a new thing to chase for the moment.

It was the SNI, someone had set System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "true"); elsewhere in the application and so it wasn't including the SNI in the ClientHello. Thank you a ton for mentioning that one.

Interesting indeed. You can see that the server rejected the connection. Usually is the Client that is doing the validation (dates, subject, SAN...)

Thanks to Steffen Ullrich in the comments pointing out that SNI can cause this issue. I found that elsewhere in this java application it was being disabled:
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

correcting this by setting it to true fixes my immediate issue.
